# Removing lens from Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: unity, 12.10, lenses

I would like to remove lens from Ubuntu's unity environment.

You might argue that I can go back to Ubuntu-Gnome classic. But I would like to retain global menu feature of Ubuntu.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you want to remove Unity, what do you want to run instead? GNOME 3? XFCE? KDE? Are you looking for an alternative desktop environment that has a global menu?

Comment: I want to be in Ubuntu Unity environment. But I don't want to have lenses showing up. Definitely not Gnome3, KDE. Do we have any other environment that has global menu? I would like to have all the look and feel of ubuntu, except lenses.

Answer (score 6):

To uninstall lens, open terminal / `Ctrl+Alt+t` then type:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-xxx
```

The xxx is the type of lens. In general, Unity use this lenses:

1. `Applications`
2. `Files`
3. `Gwibber`
4. `Photos`
5. `Shopping`