# Remove unwanted lenses from installing Unity Next

Tags: unity-dash, lenses

So I followed instruction provided [here](http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unitynext/) to set up Unity Next, and it give me two additional lenses on Ubuntu Dash. Now I'm done with it and I want to remove the additional lenses, how to do it?

[image]

Comment: It's not, I don't want to remove default lenses

Comment: It's not, but you can do in the same way... [*The xxx is the type of lens*](http://askubuntu.com/a/214983/147044)

Comment: You're right, I've mistaken it by the name of video and music lens, but that's no problem I just have to reinstall them, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Preparation**

First install the ppa-purge tool: sudo apt-get install ppa-purge or click here: ppa-purge

**Step 2: Remove software**

Now run:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:phablet-team/desktop-deps
sudo ppa-purge ppa:phablet-team/desktop-deps
```

If you're not on Raring, additionally run:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
```

This will remove the PPAs from your system, which basically means removing them from your software sources, and resetting the packages to the default versions from the official repos. See the manpage for the ppa-purge command  for more info on how it works.

Note that while the phablet-team/desktop-deps PPA is not mentioned in the compilation guide, it is mentioned in the build script.

Next you need to remove the final binaries that you compiled. Based on your description of how you ran the software, you should be able to just  run

```
rm -rf /path/to/build/directory
```

where `/path/to/build/directory` is the directory in which you built Unity Next. I think this is the directory that you would have run ./build from. If you followed the instructions without changing any paths, this directory should be ~/unity.

**Step 3 (optional): remove build dependencies**:

Note: while these commands are written in such a way as to not uninstall any software that you don't want to be uninstalled, they will automatically remove any packages that you don't need on your system (packages installed to satisfy a dependency, but not needed anymore because nothing installed depends on them). This is a completely safe result, but be aware of what is happening.

If you want to get rid of build dependencies, and are running Raring:

```
sudo apt-mark auto qt-components-ubuntu qtdeclarative5-dee-plugin indicators-client indicators-client-plugin-* qtbase5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev-tools qtdeclarative5-test-plugin libdee-qt5-dev libpulse-dev qtdeclarative5-xmllistmodel-plugin unity-lens-mock demo-assets libboost-regex1.49-dev ubuntu-mobile

# this next command may or may not work in Raring.

sudo apt-mark auto bamfdaemon debhelper dh-autoreconf gir1.2-dee-1.0 gnome-common gnome-doc-utils gobject-introspection gtk-doc-tools indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-appmenu-tools intltool libappindicator3-dev libbamf3-dev libdbusmenu-glib-dev libdbusmenu-gtk3-dev libdbusmenu-jsonloader-dev libdbustest1-dev libdee-dev libgirepository1.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libncurses5-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev metacity sqlite3 valac-0.18 libpocketsphinx-dev libsphinxbase-dev

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

If you want to get rid of build dependencies, and are running Quantal or lower:

```
sudo apt-mark auto qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin qtdeclarative5-dee-plugin indicators-client indicators-client-plugin-* qtbase5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev-tools qtdeclarative5-test-plugin libdee-qt5-dev libpulse-dev qtdeclarative5-xmllistmodel-plugin unity-lens-mock demo-assets libboost-regex1.49-dev ubuntu-mobile
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

The guide also has you install bzr: if you really don't want that on your system, run `sudo apt-get remvoe bzr`.

Comment: These didn't remove the added lenses.